# Modifying HTML text using innerHTML and/or replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbiscuits

So I have been stuck on this jQuery problem for days at this point. 
I am working on a Web Application that was derived from Mobile and my company goes through NetBiscuits for mobile.

Long story short NetBiscuits uses their own markup and I cannot get this string'[BR][BR]'from showing up in an error message. 
[BR] is the BML of line break and I need some jQuery to take that sucker out of our web app!

[ ] essentially needs to be < > or nothing (preferred)

I gave the form: errors a div id of "erMsg." Here's my code in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("erMsg").value = document.getElementById("erMsg").innerHTML(erMsg.replace('[BR][BR]', '<br><br>'));
```

I have tried countless methods and practices both using jQuery and JS, innerHTML and replace().
ANY help would be most graciously accepted.

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` is not a function, it's a property. You assign to it.

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('erMsg');
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/\[br\]/ig,'<br />');
```